# SQL Server : split string in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I want to split date in column in 3 fields, I use this query

```
SELECT  
SUBSTRING(Account.date, 1, 2) AS "Month",
SUBSTRING(Account.date, 4, 2) AS "Day",
SUBSTRING(Account.date, 7, 4) AS "Year"
FROM Account
```

Almost all data is in format `02/11/2000`, but some of it can be `02/November/2000` or `2/11/2000`.

Only common thing is that data separated by `/`. How can I separate this column using the delimiter?

Comment: How do you know if "02/11/2000" is November 2, 2000 or February 11, 2000?

Comment: You should convert Account.date to datetime and then use inbuilt function Year(), Month, Day to get result.

Comment: @jrhutch , I don't. I always assume that sequence is day/month/year

Comment: A pretty common thing that I have to deal with, as Accounting Period dates for our third party software are stored as a string value (they can't be a date, as the "13th month" is a possible accounting period--even if they could, I have no control over the types of their fields). GarethD's answer seems the cleanest for my needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surprisingly `CAST('2/November/2000' as datetime)` works (checked on SQL Server 2008), gives value **2000-11-02 00:00:00.000**

```
SELECT  
Month(CAST(Account.date AS DateTime)) "Month",
Day(CAST(Account.date AS DateTime)) "Day",
Year(CAST(Account.date AS DateTime)) "Year",

FROM Account
```

But as rightly pointed out in comment how do you know if "02/11/2000" is November 2, 2000 or February 11, 2000?

Also the spelling of Month names must be absolutely correct else conversion fails. Since you are storing dates as string there is chance that entry like November , Agust etc could have been made .

You should never store date values as strings.

Comment: Works fine if you make sure that date format is `dmy`. Add `set dateformat dmy;` before the query to make sure. +1.

Comment: yes @MikaelEriksson .. without doing set dateformat , a  value like 17/01/2000 will throw error conversion failed..thnks for pointing out

Comment: Excellent answer, well explained.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way by using `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` functions

```
select 
    LEFT(Account.date, CHARINDEX('/', Account.date) - 1),
    SUBSTRING(Account.date, CHARINDEX('/', Account.date) + 1, LEN(Account.date) - CHARINDEX('/', Account.date) - CHARINDEX('/', Account.date, CHARINDEX('/', Account.date)) - 2),
    REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(Account.date), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(Account.date)) - 1))
FROM Account
```

Comment: `RIGHT(Account.date, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(Account.date)) - 1)` . . . For the third part.  Great answer, I used this style with just that minor change

Answer (score 1):

You can abuse the [PARSENAME](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) function slightly here:

```
SELECT  FirstPart = PARSENAME(REPLACE(Account.Date, '/', '.'), 3),
        SecondPart = PARSENAME(REPLACE(Account.Date, '/', '.'), 2),
        ThirdPart = PARSENAME(REPLACE(Account.Date, '/', '.'), 1)
FROM    (VALUES
            ('02/November/2000'),
            ('2/11/2000')
        ) Account (Date);
```

Will give:

```
FirstPart   SecondPart  ThirdPart
02          November    2000
2           11          2000
```

I would however, highly recommend [storing your dates using the appropriate data type!](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type). SQL Server 2012 has the [TRY_CONVERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) function which can make such conversions easier, but you still need to know what format your string date is in, `2/11/2000` could be the 2nd November, or 11th February depending on your regional settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of CharIndex and Substring function in SQL to split the string based on delimiter.

You can check CharIndex examples here [SQL Server 2005 Using CHARINDEX() To split a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555755/sql-server-2005-using-charindex-to-split-a-string)
and here [SQL Server - find nth occurrence in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726111/sql-server-find-nth-occurrence-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your database column `account.date` contains a valid `datetime` or `date` value you should using SQLServers date functions like:

```
select month(getDate()) as "Month", 
       day(getDate()) as "Day", 
       year(getDate()) as "Year"
```

I replaced your column `account.date` by a `getDate()` to have some test values. This maps to your SQL in the following way

```
SELECT  
month(Account.date) AS "Month",
day(Account.date) AS "Day",
year(Account.date) AS "Year"
FROM Account
```

Storing these date values as varchars would be IMHO a design flaw of your database structure. Dates are formatted in multiple ways to text. This is the presentation of your database data. To process your data you would always preprocess your text dates. That is bad practice.

If you have indeed varchar values there are several SO questions like: [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(100)<BR>
SET @VALUE ='2/11/2000' <BR>
SELECT SUBSTRING(@VALUE,0,CHARINDEX('/',@VALUE,0)),

SUBSTRING(@VALUE,
CHARINDEX('/',@VALUE,0)+1,

(CHARINDEX('/',@VALUE,(CHARINDEX('/',@VALUE,0)+1)) - 
CHARINDEX('/',@VALUE,0) - 1)

),RIGHT(@VALUE,4)
```